# How to measure Engine capacity

Tags: engine, gasoline

Engine capacity, is it right to measure it in this way,,, example : 2ltr is the amount of fuel consumed at a right rpm at 100 km /hr for 10 kms as per 2ltr capacity. Someone confused my mind I don't understand. Can anyone explain how it's supposed to be, if it's correct otherwise

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Have a look at the linked question - the answers there explain what you're looking for.

Comment: A 2 litre engine is a 2000 cc (cubic centimetre) engine. It is the volume swept by all the pistons, i.e the difference between the internal volume of the cylinders with the pistons at their highest and lowest positions. Often the *nominal* capacity is quoted, for example a 2-litre engine might be actually 1991 cc. It has nothing to do with fuel consumption directly, but is loosely related because a larger engine capacity typically has a greater fuel consumption.